# HttpClient call in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing problem in calling HttpClient class and async call. I call the function List() from page_load. The calls return from the line HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(str); and never comes back to finish it.

I don't understand what mistake I am doing. Following is my code:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task<string> s= List(product); 
        }

        protected async Task<string> List(string ProductType)
        {
            string str = "http://xx.xx.com/wiki/api.php";


            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", "username", "password"))));
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(str);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            return content;
         }
```

It never executes following lines.

```
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never show what happens to the task in `Page_Load`, but given your symptoms and the fact that `Page_Load` is not `async`, I'm betting that you're calling `Result` or `Wait` instead of `await`ing it.

When you do that, you [cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). The link to my blog explains this in detail, but the gist is that `await` will capture and restore the current "context". In ASP.NET, this is a request context, and the request context only allows one thread executing in it at a time. So, if you call `Result` or `Wait` (while you're in the request context), you'll block a thread in that request context until the `Task<string>` completes. Meanwhile, when the `HttpClient` gets its response, it tries to resume after the `await client.GetAsync(str)`. But the request context will only allow one thread in at a time, and that thread is blocked waiting for the `Task` to complete. Since `List` cannot complete because the context is busy, you have a deadlock.

To prevent deadlocks, follow these two [best practices (from my recent MSDN article)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx):

1. Use `async` all the way. That is, use `await` instead of `Result` or `Wait`.
2. Use `ConfigureContext(false)` in your "library" code, i.e., every `await` in `List` should actually be `await ... .ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: Thanks Stephen for helping me. It helps.